# ¿Cómo introducir y capturar datos desde un Datagriedview directamente?

Tags: c#, array, datagrid, datagridview, matriz

Tengo un código en `C# net.Framework` que genera una matriz cuadrada de 5x5.

Deseo poder ingresar datos haciendo click sobre una celda ya generada del datagridview y luego cargar los datos ingresados mediante un botón.

Para terminar, me gustaría mostrar en un Label el dato introducido en una celda seleccionada.

Este es mi código:

````
   int[,] mat = new int[5, 5];
   //LLENAR MATRIZ
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    mat[i, j] = *Aquí no se que colocar*
                }
            }

   //MOSTRAR MATRIZ
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    DGV_Mat.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = mat[i, j];
                }
            }```
````